# Using catch block for program flow/making decisions

Tags: java

Is using a catch block for decision making/program flow in the way I did in the following code snippet a good idea?  If I didn't do this, I would have to:

- allow for any type of input via the Scanner
- test if the input (string) equals Q or q
- if not, test if its some other non-integer type and print error if not an integer
- parse/cast the string to an int

That seems like a lot more work than what I have below.  Is the fact that I am allowing my program to throw an Exception for an expected value (Q/q) and using the catch block as normal program flow a "best practice"?  Is there some other way to solving this problem that I am not considering?

```
try
{ 
    System.out.print("Enter the numerator: ");
    num = scan.nextInt();
    goodNumerator = true;
} 
catch (InputMismatchException ex )
{ 
    String input = scan.next();
    if (input.toLowerCase().equals("q"))
    {
        System.out.println("User exited");
        System.exit(0);
    }   
    else { System.out.println("Please enter a valid numerator"); }
}
```

Comment: Catching exceptions is an expensive operation and should not be an integrated part of the normal workflow. As the name implies - it should be an exception - not a normal case.

Comment: Calling `System.exit` is also not a good way to stop an application.

Comment: Understood - it's just temporary at this time.

Comment: Why not just use `hasNextInt` from `Scanner` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit more work, but highly recommended. It makes for a better code, because:

- It follows the standard programming conventions
- Makes the code more efficient. Handling processing flow via exceptions is more expensive, and you are re-doing part of the processing in your catch block.
- Makes the code more readable and maintainable for other programmers that come along.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with this, as long as it's not affecting optimization. try comparing performance of the "try-catch" code with the other approach. correct me if wrong

Comment: This is not enough answer. better to explain with source code